# Reaching a control, within a ContentControl from view's code behind

Tags: xaml, uwp

My view's XAML is only containing a custom control.

A bit further, in a Resource Dictionary, I have a Style for this custom control, and inside this, I have a TextBox. My goal would be to reach this TextBox from the view's code behind, and set it's focus, when the view's DataContext changed.

I tried to use x:Name to give a name to the custom control on the view's XAML, and also give a name to the TextBox inside the control's style (so essentially trying to reach it from code behind like: this.MyCustomControl.SearchTextBox). This did not work.

What would be the best practice to solve this issue?

Comment: Is this TextBox inside the ControlTemplate of the custom control?

Comment: Yes, it is inside the ControlTemplate

Answer (score 1):

This is what I would do.

1. Create a `TemplatePart` attribute on top of your custom control for the `TextBox`.

   `[TemplatePart(Name = "YourTextBoxName", Type = typeof(TextBox))]`
2. Then inside the `OnApplyTemplate` override method, get a reference of the `TextBox`.

   ```
   // You might want to add property error handling here
   // so if the TextBox is not found, throw an exception.
   // Doing so forces other people will have to implement
   // the SAME PART in their own stylings.
   _textBox = (TextBox)GetTemplateChild("YourTextBoxName");
   ```
3. Then all you need is to create a public method `SetFocus` that your code behind class can have access to.

   `public void SetFocus() => _textBox.Focus(FocusState.Programmatic);`

Answer (score 0):

Try visual tree helper

```
            VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(object, index)
```

[msdn link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.visualtreehelper(v=vs.110).aspx)